# python: Binary/Hex equivalent of decimal

Tags: python, hex, decimal

I've been attempting to make a program to find specific hexadecimal digits of pi using the [Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula#BBP_digit-extraction_algorithm_for_.CF.80), but I can't find any way of storing the computed section of pi accurately.

While I am aware of decimal, unfortunately I'm dealing in hexadecimal digits, and I was essentially wondering if Python has any way of storing floating-point numbers with arbitrary precision in binary/hexadecimal?

Comment: Something like [float.hex()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.hex)?

Comment: Just store them as a string?

Comment: While that would be nice, I'm looking to store something along the lines of 1000 digits after the decimal point, which floats aren't excellent for, and nor are strings, given that I need to add thigns up.